# Why Event object can not been wait again?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

```
from threading import Thread, Event
import time

def countdown(n, start_evt):
    start_evt.wait()
    print('start counting')
    while n > 0:
        print('T-minus', n)
        n -= 1
        time.sleep(1)
        if n == 96:
            start_evt.clear()

start_evt = Event()
print('launching counting')

t = Thread(target=countdown, args=(100, start_evt))
t.start()
time.sleep(5)
start_evt.set()
print('countdown is running')
```

I am new to the python thread using python cookbook.I set `start_evt.clear()` in the while.But when `n==96` this thread did not wait again,why?this is in page 500.It continue counting down like blew.

```
launching counting
countdown is running
start counting
T-minus 100
T-minus 99
T-minus 98
T-minus 97
T-minus 96
T-minus 95
T-minus 94
T-minus 93
T-minus 92
```

Comment: maybe your `start_evt.wait()` should be _inside_ the loop, else there's nothing to stop the counter.

Comment: oh I am a big idiot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your loop has no way to wait for an event since the wait statement is *outside* the loop.

I would do this:

```
def countdown(n, start_evt):
    print('start counting')
    while n > 0:
        start_evt.wait()
        print('T-minus', n)
        n -= 1
        time.sleep(1)
        if n == 96:
            start_evt.clear()
```

now, because the `wait()` call is *inside* the loop, it loops until event is cleared, then it stops